# CSV matrix of coordinates to Raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinates

Is it possible to create a raster in QGIS from a CSV file that is a “matrix of coordinates” without transforming it into a vector?

I explain: My data is a matrix of 5500 columns and 175 rows, it is 962500 points. The Columns are the X coordinates and the Rows are the Y coordinates. The values in the matrix are the Z coordinate of each point. The X distance between points is 0,04 cm and the Y distance is 0,80 cm. I could try reorganizing the data in a way that I have just three coordinates in columns X, Y, Z for all the 962500 points. However, it means an additional step and I would have to do it repeatedly as my experiment produces the CSV file described before.

How can I create the raster in QGIS from the original matrix?

Comment: what you have looks like a "raster to point" output; in order to read it as a csv you have to modify the aspect of your file, so you end up with x, y and z fields, instead of x1...xn, vs y1...yn fields, I would try that in R; then go from point to raster

Comment: If you add a correct header this could be read in as an ASCI grid, I think

Comment: Your data sounds already as a raster in some way, but you need a header to describe its organization, could you provide a exerpt of your data? the first 3 lines for instance

Comment: Yes indeed the data is somehow organized as a raster.  
The original CSV file does not come with the headers. It looks like this:  
  4.64,4.62,4.64,4.68,4.69,4.76,4.79  

  4.7,4.71,4.61,4.64,4.64,4.67,4.69  

  4.33,4.44,4.5,4.48,4.52,4.58,4.61  The delimiters are commas (,). I could include the headers. For columns are the X coordinates and headers for the rows  are the Y coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a header for your data. It is plenty of formats, you just need to choose one supported by GDAL (see: http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html)

Here the description of the GRASS ASCII taken from [r.in.ascii.](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.in.ascii.html), which take into account the different size of X and Y dimensions:

> The GRASS ASCII input file has a header section which describes the
>   location and size of the data, followed by the data itself.
>
> The header has 6 lines:
>
> ```
> north:   xxxxxx.xx 
> south:   xxxxxx.xx 
> east:    xxxxxx.xx 
> west:    xxxxxx.xx 
> rows:    r  
> cols:    c
> ```
>
> The north, south, east, and west field values entered are the
>   coordinates of the edges of the geographic region. The rows and cols
>   field values entered describe the dimensions of the matrix of data to
>   follow. The data which follows is r rows of c integers.
>
> Optionally the following parameters can be defined in the header
>   section:
>
> ```
> null: nn 
> type: float 
> multiplier: 2.
> ```
>
> "null" defines a string or number to be converted to NULL value (no
>   data). "type" defines the data type (int, float double) and is not
>   required. "multiplier" is an optional parameter to multiply each cell
>   value.